# Jquery/Ajax remove div from page loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a script that calls a php page via jquery/ajax. The results would look like this:

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title1</th>
      <th scope="col">Title2</th>
      <th scope="col">Title3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><?php echo $wait_list; ?></tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <div id="statcount">Rows: <?php echo $row_count; ?></div>
</div>
```

When this is called via the jquery/ajax call it displays the table information and at the end the div information. However I dont want the bottom div to show, I actually want it removed from the data, I just have it there so I can grab the count and put it in a different div from the script calling this file so I dont have to make 2 seperate jquery/ajax calls. So when the jquery/ajax call is made it runs this on success:

```
  function updateList(data){
      $('#rowcount').html($('#statcount',data).html());
      $('#statcount',data).remove();
      $("#waitlist").html(data);
  }
```

As you can see Im using that div to populate a seperate area on the page. But once that is done I dont want the div from the php page to show up in #waitlist. I tried the remove() function as you see above but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: A really sucky way: hide the offending `div` with CSS - `<div style="display:none"><div id="statcount">Rows: <?php echo $row_count; ?></div></div>`

Comment: @thirtydot: Actually I tried that, but it leaves a spacing in the table rows at the end.

Comment: @thirtydot: You know what, that actually worked. I just moved the div instead the table tags then manually set it to display:none. That is yucky, but if there is no alternative then I will use it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing data as the scope parameter for jQuery selector and hence you are not getting any matches.
Try this:

```
function updateList(data)
{       
    var lData = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");
    $('#rowcount').html($('#statcount',lData).html());       
    $('#statcount',lData).remove();       
    $("#waitlist").html(data);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#statcount',data).remove();
```

I am not sure what value you are passing the function `updateList(data)` as data, but it seems on your html you have no other value alongside the id for `<div id="statcount">`

I am assuming that you are passing a number, but if thats the case then your `<div id="statcount">` should have been `<div id="statcount1">` or whatever value you pass as `data`

Comment: The whole page result is being passed as data. Im using a jquery plugin called arte, which is a plugin for real time ajax calls. So on success I can specific a function to run which passes the returned results via the data variable. There is only one div called statcount in the return data variable. I tried $('#statcount',data).remove(); but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

A better way (unless there are zillions of rows) than the one I gave in my comments to your question would be to get rid of this:

```
<div>
  <div id="statcount">Rows: <?php echo $row_count; ?></div>
</div>
```

and to count the number of rows using jQuery, with something like:

```
var rowCount = $("tr", data).length;
$('#rowcount').html('Rows: ' + rowCount);
```

Or alternatively, you could do this:

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%" rowcount="<?php echo $row_count; ?>">
```

and use jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to extract the rowcount.

Comment: On the tr count code, is there a way to count tr that doesnt have a certain class? There is an additional tr if there are notes for a row, so I just want to count the tr that doesnt have the notes class assigned to it.

Comment: @John: `"tr:not([class=notes])"`