# converting jquery object to html

Tags: jquery, html

I am calling an ajax function and on the call back i am getting html data .As the data has uncessary html tags ,I wanted to remove those tags and append it to my table .For that i converted my html to jquery object , removed all the tags and now i want to convert it back to html . I know i have used a wrong for loop.Any suggestions will be appreciated on how to convert the jquery object ,(arr in this case to html data ).

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Content("~/SyndromicQuery/QueryPeriod")',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            selectedItem: selectedItem,
            startdate: startdate,
            enddate: enddate,
            queryid: queryid
        },
        success: function (data) {

            var jqObj = $.parseHTML(data)
            var arr = jqObj;
            arr.splice(6, 1);
            arr.splice(7, 1);
            arr.splice(9, 1);
            arr.splice(9, 7);
            arr.splice(0, 7)
            arr.splice(0, 1);
            arr.splice(1, 4);
            var test = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                test += "" + arr[i].innerhtml + "";

                $('canvas').remove();

                //  $("#tblresult").append(html);
                $('#divtest').html(test)
                //  $("#divtest").empty().append(arr);
```

Comment: If you're calling your own service, it should be responsible for sending down *correct* html.

Comment: Please post what you are receiving so we can address this quickly and without confusion

Comment: Could you add an example of the string inside 'data'?

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!Doctype html />


           
<html>
<head>

Comment: <head>
          
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Chart.js"></script> 

     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/theme/jquery.ui.all.css" />
    
    
          
</head>

Comment: The html starts with <!Doctype html> <html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Chart.js"></script> <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/theme/jquery.ui.all.css" /></head> <body> </body> </html

Comment: Removing <doctype html> also doesnt work .Only parse html is working if you want put in jquery object.

Comment: @ErikPhilips ,I found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550374/jquery-ajax-remove-div-from-page-loaded-by-ajax  .. var lData = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");

Comment: var lData = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");     // creating a variable and storing html in that variable
 
$('#statclear', lData).remove(); // Here statclear is th div i wanted to remove 

 $('#divtest').html(lData); // Finally #divtest is the div i wanted to append after removing statclear div

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do the following (unless I've misunderstood your code):

```
success: function (data) {

    $('#divtest').html($(data).empty());

}
```

Or, for example, for an inner element `div.test#id`:

```
success: function (data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $data.find("#divclear").remove();

    $('#divtest').html($data);
    // OR (depending on what's in 'data')
    $('#divtest').html($data.children());

}
```

Comment: ..it is throwing an error if i use $('#divtest').html($(data).find('#divclear').clear()); here divclear is a div i wanted to remove

Comment: Yea..There are two tags in the html ..Html is as follows <html><divclear> </divclear> <divtest> </divtest> <html> . Now i want find divclear id and remove it

Comment: Try what I've just written

Comment: Sounds like you're missing an enclosing bracket somewhere.

Comment: @EzSlaver ..what i noticed is when   var $data = $(data); is throwing error because you are creating jquery object from html . From my previous code ,if you put parsehtml ..it will work but again i have to convert that jquery object to html

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/
converts string into array of dom elements.

This definitely works. **appendChild** is pure javascript function.
To CONVERT Jquery OBJECT to HTML DO this >> >>

```
var $data = $(document.createElement('div'))[0];
arr.forEach(function(v){$data.appendChild(v)});
```

& in your case

```
$('#divtest').html($data);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/kjevr/3/

Comment: ,My question was to convert the query object back to html ,because this htmldata is being used by charts in my .cshtml in mvc view. So My main intention is just to remove some div tags and append back .

Comment: that's what i have done...taken query/string use `parseHTML(string)` on it and then append elements from the returned array.

Comment: ok instead of appending each element into where you want, you want to have one html element that you can handle through jquery right.

Comment: Muhammad I am sorry if my question confused you ..See first there is ajax call ,On sucess function i am getting success: function (data) {}.This 'data' has html .I dont need all the div emlements in that html .I want to remove some div elements and i have to update back this html with the removed divs to a table in my mvc .cshtml view .

Comment: what part are you having trouble with removing or adding back to html.

Comment: This is **really** resource inneficient. Use at least `.html()`, at best `.innerHTML`.

Comment: i am assuming you had trouble getting pure html element. I am not sure why you had trouble with what you have but use what i have done it works. Use the loop method i've used.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer  I found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550374/jquery-ajax-remove-div-from-page-loaded-by-ajax ...my code goes 
var lData = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");     // creating a variable and storing html in that variable
 
$('#statclear', lData).remove(); // Here statclear is th div i wanted to remove 

 $('#divtest').html(lData); // Finally #divtest is the div i wanted to append after removing statclear div